# Simulating VHDL Modelsim Dual-port RAM with 2 Clocks

Tags: vhdl, ram, modelsim, test-bench

I need help with the testbench for a Dualport RAM with 2 clocks where address A (write) is synchronized with CLK A and address B (read) with CLK B.
Here is the code in ModelSim:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity RAM is 
port(
    d_in    : in 
   std_logic_vector(7 downto 
    0);
    ADDRA   : in 
    std_logic_vector(2 downto 
    0);
    ADDRB   : in 
    std_logic_vector(2 downto 
    0);
    WEA     : in std_logic ;
    REA  : in std_logic ;
    CLKA    : in std_logic ;
    CLKB    : in std_logic ;
    d_out   : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);

 end RAM ;
 Architecture behav of RAM is

type Memory is ARRAY(7 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal mem : Memory;

BEGIN

process(CLKA)
begin
    if(rising_edge(CLKA)) then 
        if(WEA = '1') then
            mem(to_integer(signed(ADDRA))) <= d_in;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

    process(CLKB)
begin
    if(rising_edge(CLKB)) then
        if ( REA = '1') then
          d_out <= mem(to_integer(signed(ADDRB))) ;
    end if;
    end if;
end process;
end behav ;
```

I have been trying to make the testbench file by different strategies but it never worked properly and keeps giving me errors.

Comment: See [ask]. `it never worked properly and keeps giving me errors` is a bit vague for a problem statement of an unseen testbench.

Answer (score 1):

The RAM addressing should probably be unsigned.

```
  mem(to_integer(unsigned(ADDRA))) <= d_in;
```

and

```
   d_out <= mem(to_integer(unsigned(ADDRB))) ;
```

With signed addressing an address input of `b"111"` will correspond to the two's complement integer `-1` instead of `7`.

Edit:
I made a, very simple, working testbench here: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Mq7

Comment: Comment or ... (what's the question?)

Comment: @user1155120 I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Are you implying that I shouldn't try to help because the question is not perfect?

Comment: The OP is either implicitly asking for a reference to an implementation of a testbench for a two port RAM or is hoping someone will write one (there isn't one on Stackoverflow).   See [answer] the section Answer well-asked questions', is the question [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Since the type `memory` is defined as an `ARRAY(7 downto 0)` it is not unimportant whether you use signed or unsigned. In fact the design will crash with a out of range fatal. As shown here: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Mq7
I'll agree that I didn't answer the implied question. But now I've gone ahead an made a working example for OP, so perhaps he got what he wanted.